# H2 oracle compatilibty mode with spring boot 3 & hibernate 6.2.5.final does not work for like queries

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, migration, h2

Im using h2 in memory database in oracle compatibility mode in my spring boot 3 app for test purposes.

During migration from sb2 to sb3 I have found out that each like query build by criteria jpa api is no longer working, after short research it turns out that like queries have additional char escaping added.

For example:

`select x from y where a like ? escape ''`

Previously escape was not added to queries (sb 2):

`select x from y where a like ?`

how to disable this out of the box escaping ?

versions:
h2: 1.4.200
Spring-boot: 3.1.1
hibernate-core: 6.2.5
sqlDialect: h2

Comment: This is a known issue of Hibernate ORM https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16277 It was incorrectly closed as a duplicate of another unrelated issue.

Comment: Do you know any workaround?

Comment: It still not working in Spring Boot 3.2.0 version. I hadn't this problem in 2.7.5 version.

If somebody has problem with criteriaBuilder problem, I fixed this with adding third parameter to criteriaBuilder.like(foo, foo, '/')

Answer (score 1):

I have removed mode:ORACLE from jdbc h2 URL and it works fine. Not the best solution, but still worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but you can add the "escape '\'" to your queries which will stop it putting the empty one in there.  This will change your queries though and treat backslashes as escape characters so you'll need to watch out for that.